# Symfony Doctrine Listener - update entity before it's deleted in preRemove event

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

**UPDATE**

This does work if `flush` is called in the `preRemove` listener, but does *not* work if `flush` is not called. The reason it was not working initially was due to some other code I had that prevented the `flush` from being called.

Just wanted to mention this in case anyone else comes across this post.

---

I have a [Symfony Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) that is registered on the Doctrine `preRemove` event. In the `preRemove` method on the listener, I want to update the entity that is being removed before it is deleted from the database. Here's some sample code:

```
public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entity->setDeletedOn(new \DateTime());
    $entity->setDeletedBy($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
    dump($entity); // this shows the updated columns
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush(); // tried adding a flush to see if it would work
}
```

This doesn't work. I can see the `preRemove` method is definitely getting called and is setting the `deletedOn` and `deletedBy` properties, but when I look at the database queries in the symfony profiler, it doesn't contain an `UPDATE` statement, only the `DELETE` statement.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something, or if there's a better way to accomplish this? It seems that if I want to create or update a *different* entity, this works fine. But if I try to update the *same* entity that is being deleted, Doctrine never issues the `UPDATE` statement.

*NOTE: The DB tables have after insert and after update triggers that copy the row into an archive table. I need an `UPDATE` statement to run right before the `DELETE` statement, so the record will get copied to the archive table with the appropriate values for `deletedOn` and `deletedBy`. An after delete trigger won't work, because the database doesn't know who the current Symfony user is*

Comment: Just FYI: You should make sure `$entity` is an instance of your class that provides the `setDeleted[On|By]` methods.

Comment: This is a simplified example of the code to show the problem. The actual class uses a reflection method to make sure the entity has setDeletedOn and setDeletedBy methods. Considered an interface and checking if the entity implements it, but using the reflection method for now. It also has prePersist and preUpdate methods which work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the row trumps all other operations, when doctrine calculates the minimum amount of work to update the row, if you delete the row, it'll only do that and not worry about updates.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. So it sounds like there's no way to do this with a doctrine event listener, and instead I'm going to need a service to manually update the columns and then call remove each time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `postRemove` method instead of `preRemove`. You can perform the `flush` method in `postRemove` to update any other entity.